# Indexing the logs into different types(schema) in elastic search based on matching patterns

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

For example here is my log file

```
[2016-10-18 12:05:53.228] log example

[2016-10-18 11:55:53.228] 19249060-91df-11e6-be68-753fa0e2c729 logg example

[2016-10-18 11:35:53.228] 19249060-91ff-11e6-be68-753fa0e2c729 loggg example /api/userbasic/userinfo?requestedUserId=19249060-91df-11e6-be68-753fa0e2c729
```

grok filter for my log.here i have used multiple patterns

```
filter { 
    grok {
    match => [
        "message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp1}\] %{WORDS_EX:msg}",
        "message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp2}\] %{UUID:user_id1} %{WORDS_EX:msg2} %{URIPATHPARAM:path}",
        "message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp3}\] %{UUID:user_id2} %{WORDS_EX:msg3}"

    ]
}

}
```

now i want index the logs into elasticsearch with different types(schema) like
logstash/type1,
logstash/type2,
logstash/type3,

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a problem with your filters: the grok pattern are evaluated one by one and when one pattern match, the others will not be evaluated, so the pattern needs to be sorted from the most specific (the one with `%{URIPATHPARAM:path}`) to the most general (the one with `%{WORDS_EX:msg}`) like so:

```
"message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp2}\] %{UUID:user_id1} %{WORDS_EX:msg2} %{URIPATHPARAM:path}",
"message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp3}\] %{UUID:user_id2} %{WORDS_EX:msg3}",
"message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp1}\] %{WORDS_EX:msg}"
```

Then you can use the presence/absence of various fields with [conditionnals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) like so:

```
if [path] {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
    }
} else if [user_id2] {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
    }
} else {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
    }
}
```